# Android Studio app is crashing (it is look like the app is keep changing to another interface)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Currently, I develop an application using Android Studio.  The code and the logcat shows no error, but the application keep crash. I had try invalidate/restart, clean and rebuild project.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code relate

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.c0v3r7hz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ImageViewerActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FindFriendsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PhoneLoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private TabLayout myTabLayout;
    private TabsAccessAdapter myTabAccessorAdapter;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;
    private String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("c0v3r7H!z");

        myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
        myTabAccessorAdapter = new TabsAccessAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabAccessorAdapter);

        myTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser == null) {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else {

            updateUserStatus("online");
            VerifyUserExistance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            updateUserStatus("offline");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            updateUserStatus("offline");
        }
    }

    private void VerifyUserExistance() {
        String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if((dataSnapshot.child("name").exists())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    SendUserToSettingsActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_logout_option)
        {
            updateUserStatus("offline");
            mAuth.signOut();
            SendUserToLoginActivity();

        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_settings_option){
            SendUserToSettingsActivity();

        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_create_group_option)
        {
            RequestNewGroup();

        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_find_friends_option)
        {
            SendUserToFindFriendsActivity();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void RequestNewGroup() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialog);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Group Name: ");

        final EditText groupNameField = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        groupNameField.setHint("e.g 3 BIS UTHM");
        builder.setView(groupNameField);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              String groupName = groupNameField.getText().toString();
              if (TextUtils.isEmpty(groupName)){
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please write Group Name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              else {
                  CreateNewGroup(groupName);

              }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    private void CreateNewGroup(final String groupName) {
    RootRef.child("Groups").child(groupName).setValue("")
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, groupName + "group is Created Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }

    private void SendUserToSettingsActivity() {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }

    private void SendUserToFindFriendsActivity() {
        Intent findFriendsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FindFriendsActivity.class);
        startActivity(findFriendsIntent);
    }

    private void updateUserStatus(String state)
    {
        String saveCurrentTime, saveCurrentDate;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

        HashMap<String, Object> onlineStateMap = new HashMap<>();
        onlineStateMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
        onlineStateMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
        onlineStateMap.put("state", state);

        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("userState")
                .updateChildren(onlineStateMap);

    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


    private Button LoginButton, PhoneButton;
    private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword;
    private TextView NeedNewAccountLink, ForgetPasswordLink;

    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        InitializeFields();
    try {
            NeedNewAccountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SendUserToRegisterActivity();
                }


            });}
    catch (NullPointerException ignored){
    }


        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AllowUserToLogin();
            }
        });

        PhoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent phoneLoginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PhoneLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(phoneLoginIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void AllowUserToLogin() {

        String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else{

            loadingBar.setTitle("Sign In");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                                UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("device_token")
                                        .setValue(deviceToken)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error"+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        PhoneButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.phone_login_button);
        UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
        ForgetPasswordLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forget_password_link);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (currentUser == null){
            SendUserToMainActivity();
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToRegisterActivity() {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }

}
```

**Here are some of the logcat. Thank you in advanced.**

```
    2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
2020-05-31 22:24:33.394 16021-16021/com.example.c0v3r7hz I/art:     at void com.example.c0v3r7hz.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:48)
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.c0v3r7hz"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'


}
```

Comment: can you update your question with app level build.gradle file

Comment: i had add build.gradle

Comment: how often is it occuring ?

Comment: This is first time, for this kind of result.

Comment: Is it occurring everytime you launch  app?

Comment: yeah, for this application.. it is happen everytime i launch the app

Comment: That log is usually not fatal.  Are you sure there's not an actual crash in the logs?

Comment: @RyanM yeah its crashing app I am also getting this problem but its crashing my app on second launch not first one I checked for this as you said in some of threads it is mentioned its just an warning and could not cause errror but it is causing error. And I tried to enable multiDex it didn't worked I am getting this error after upgrading android studio to 4.0 I am not sure wheather it is the reason

Answer (score 0):

The app was crash at the first time because the currentUser not exist.

So I had make SendUsertoMainActivity as comment at the first launch.

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);

        if (currentUser == null){
          //  SendUserToMainActivity();
        }
    }
```